# shortcut to amend values in one column according to criteria in another

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

I'm New to VBA and finding my way around. I'm writing a macro which searches column 6 for postage method and enters the correct postage price (which often changes) in column 14.
I've started to use 'if statements' and it's working. However there are a total of 28 postage methods (and that could increase a few) I know there are shortcuts. I'm thinking this could possibly be done in an array which I could later edit as price changes

```
Sub Amend()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim row As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Long


Lastrow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row

If Lastrow > 1 Then

For row = 2 To Lastrow


'postage


If Sheets(2).Cells(row, 6).Value = "Austria Tracked" Then
Sheets(2).Cells(row, 14).Value = 4.79

End If

If Sheets(2).Cells(row, 6).Value = "International DDU shipments" Then
Sheets(2).Cells(row, 14).Value = 4.27

End If


If Sheets(2).Cells(row, 6).Value = " Landmark Belgium DDU" Then
Sheets(2).Cells(row, 14).Value = 4.27

End If

If Sheets(2).Cells(row, 6).Value = "France Untracked" Then
Sheets(2).Cells(row, 14).Value = 2.42

End If

If Sheets(2).Cells(row, 6).Value = "GLS France" Then
Sheets(2).Cells(row, 14).Value = 5.27

End If
```

I want to keep it simple but should I be using an array or a vlookup?

Comment: Would the VLookup worksheet function do what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multiple Criteria Lookup

- Copy the code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Adjust the values in the **constants** section.
- For each `Method` you add, you have to add the `Price` in the same position.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Amend()
    Const Proc As String = "Amend"
    On Error GoTo cleanError

    ' Define Constants.
    Const SheetNameOrIndex As Variant = 2 ' Sheet Name is safer than index.
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const MethodColumn As Variant = 6  ' e.g. 6 or "F"
    Const PriceColumn As Variant = 14  ' e.g. 14 or "N"

    Dim MethodValue As Variant, PriceValue As Variant

    MethodValue = Array("Austria Tracked", _
                        "International DDU shipments", _
                        "Landmark Belgium DDU", _
                        "France Untracked", _
                        "GLS France")

    PriceValue = Array(4.79, _
                       4.27, _
                       4.27, _
                       2.42, _
                       5.27)

    ' Check if MethodValue and PriceValue Arrays have the same number
    ' of elements (columns).
    Dim ubV As Long: ubV = UBound(MethodValue)
    If UBound(PriceValue) <> ubV Then Exit Sub

    ' Copy values of Method and Price Columns to Method and Price Arrays.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetNameOrIndex)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Columns(MethodColumn).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    Dim Method As Variant
    Method = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, MethodColumn), rng).Value
    Set rng = Nothing
    Dim ubMP As Long: ubMP = UBound(Method)
    Dim Price As Variant
    Price = ws.Cells(FirstRow, PriceColumn).Resize(ubMP).Value

    ' Modify values in Price Array.
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To ubMP
        For j = 0 To ubV
            If Method(i, 1) = MethodValue(j) Then
                Price(i, 1) = PriceValue(j)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Erase Method

    ' Write values of Price Array to Price Range.
    ws.Cells(FirstRow, PriceColumn).Resize(ubMP).Value = Price

   ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation, "Success"

    Exit Sub

cleanError:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred in '" & Proc & "'." & vbCr _
         & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbCr & Err.Description _
           , vbCritical, Proc & " Error"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I ran the code exactly as you had it and although it went right through with no errors it did not make the price amendments. I'm wondering ig I need to change any of the code (I haven't added the extra postage methods yet and assumed it would still run and make changes to the five postage companies I identified? I'm wondering if I need to rename sheets or something like that?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)` actually means the sheet on the 2nd Tab and not necessarily `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")` and it could also be e.g. be a `chart`. Now when you move the 2nd Tab to another location, the code will NOT work correctly. Therefore it is better to use the `Tab name` e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")`, which is in parentheses in `VBE`. Now when you rename the Tab, again, the code will NOT work correctly. it is usually best to use the `code name` e.g. `Sheet2`, the name not in parentheses in `VBE`. Note that you use the code name as is i.e. you do not use `Thisworkbook...`.

Comment: So the sheet I am working on is actually the second sheet in the workbok and it is called "Sorted1", so is the correct thing to say ..... ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sorted1")

Comment: So Set sh = ActiveSheet  should say    Set sh=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sorted1") ?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I prefer `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted1")` to make it immediately clear that it is a worksheet. I have declared `SheetNameOrIndex` as `Variant` so you can use both ways, either `"Sorted1"` or just `2`, preferring the first one of course.

Comment: Note also that `ThisWorkbook` means the workbook containing this code. So if you are running this code from another workbook, you should use the name of the workbook e.g. `Workbooks("Postage.xlsx")` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215481/discussion-between-stephen-callaghan-and-vbasic2008).

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please. You only must maintain `arrPrices` array. Each product must be separated by a comma, and product to be separated by its price using "|". You can extend the array as you need. The array can also be loaded on the fly if you will have two rows in a sheet keeping the product name on first and the price on the second:

```
Sub Amend()
Dim sh As Worksheet, row As Long, El As Variant, Lastrow As Long, arrPrices As Variant
Dim arrInt As Variant

Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet

Lastrow = sh.Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).row
arrPrices = Split("Austria Tracked|4.79,International DDU shipments|1.27,Landmark Belgium DDU|4.27,France Untracked|2.42,GLS France|5,27", ",")
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False   
 If Lastrow > 1 Then
    For row = 2 To Lastrow
        For Each El In arrPrices
            arrInt = Split(El, "|")
            If Sheets(2).Cells(row, 6).value = arrInt(0) Then
                sh.Sheets(2).Cells(row, 14).value = arrInt(1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next row
 End If
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I used your code like model, but take care, please: You calculate the last row for column D:D and process the date in column 6 (F:F). Please, check and be sure that the last row calculation is appropriate and correlate them if necessary...

I supposed that each product may appear only once during iteration. Is this assumption correct?